# Enable verbose comments when running with '-d'

Tags: origen-sdk

I would like to enable verbose comments from the command line, preferably just tied to running Origen with '-d'.  What is the best way to do this?  I currently have it tied to the 'mode' but this is not ideal.

Comment: I see from this answer, using -d at least used to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079291/standards-for-logging-text-for-pattern-flow-debug
However it does not anymore (which is probably good actually).

-verbose works, but it not documented with either 'origen -h' or 'origen g -h' - though it IS in the guides.  I assume this is the preferred solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes all commands should support `-verbose` to enable this.

In the past it was coupled to running with the debugger enabled, however it was intentionally de-coupled some time ago.

It is documented here, though I see that it is not mentioned in the command -h output (though it should be) - https://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/misc/logger/#Changing_the_Console%E2%80%99s_Verbosity_Level